# MediaWiki Special Characters in file name issue

Tags: php, mediawiki

When I upload a file onto mediawiki with Special Characters in the name it mangles the filename into something that looks like this:

Waterford_(DÃ¡il_Ã‰ireann_constituency).png

when it actually writes it to the file when it should actually look like this:

Waterford_(Dáil_Éireann_constituency).png

Which means that when another page links to that file it comes up as a broken image link because it's looking for

http://mysite.com/wiki/images/Waterford_(Dáil_Éireann_constituency).png

I don't want to prevent people from using special characters as often they copy the files from wikipedia which supports special characters, and I think it's something to do with the way my host handles files.
So it would be preferable if there was some way to intercept the way that mediawiki creates the files so that the filepath would be free from special characters while all the references would still work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that or how to find that out

Comment: the website itself is http://www.politicswiki.ie btw

Comment: It seems that the filename it's getting in is all messed up as well, I don't know why that would happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaWiki is 100% UTF-8 safe, but something somewhere in your Apache/PHP configuration is mangling UTF-8 into ISO 8859-1 (Latin1).  Start by making sure your PHP install has `mbstring` enabled as specified here:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/PHP_configuration

If you're stuck with a messed-up host, then this Talk page has some clues for stabbing your Wiki with a knife to make it dumb down filenames:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:Configuring_file_uploads#Image_File_Names

Comment: Also as to the second part of your answer I've read that and it hasn't helped

Comment: Turned out it was something in my hosts set up, I've changed hosts and this has resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak on how and where to do this in Mediawiki, but a good way to do this would be to `urlencode()` the file name. Percent encoded file names should work on all platforms, and it's easy to restore them into proper form when necessary.

Comment: Yeah a major part of issue is I need an answer that works on MediaWiki, I've been searching through the source code here for a couple of hours trying to find the part where it decides what to name the file, it's needlessly complicated.

Comment: @Stephen yeah.  As a general pointer, every mention of `$_FILES` and `move_uploaded_files` is worth a look, but you probably already know that.

Comment: Thanks but that hasn't really helped I think the files are tied to their names. As in the file Image:Waterford_(Dáil_Éireann_constituency).png has to be at /wiki/images/Waterford_(Dáil_Éireann_constituency).png